# Intersection between a line and a circle in polar coordinate system

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I have a point p1 connected to p2 in a polar coordinate system. This forms an "arc" or i believe part of a spiral..

What I would need to know, is how I could calculate the intersection between the circle (center at P1) and the above mentioned line, with only the radius of the circle, P1 and P2 given as theta/rho informations.

Its the first time I work with polar coordinates to please bear with me, its unexplored teritory.

it does not have to be precise, an approximation within +-2% is more than enough.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, without an exact equation for the "arc" or "spiral" solving this isn't going to be an exact solution, there even can't be given error bounds because you don't even know the actual position. However, from the above figure, my best guess is that as $\theta$ is increasing, $r$ is increasing. You could assume proportionality between $r$ and $\theta$ for the arc as below

$$\frac{r-70000}{20000} = \frac{\theta - \frac{2\pi}{3}}{\frac{5\pi}{8}}$$

Comment: yes  r and θ are increasing proportionally... sorry, for the stupid question, but the formula you posted is what exactly?

Comment: I just thought of it is a line - so for a given increase in $\theta$ there is a proportional increase in $r$ - so given the ratio of $\delta r$ will always be equal to $\delta \theta$

Comment: that makes sense... thank you... but how do I get the theta/rho values of the intersection?